# конструктор страниц через Админку Django

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Дали тестовое задание на джуна, Разработать конструктор из блоков лендинга, которым можно управлять из Django админ панели. В сроки уже не укладываюсь да и уровень не мой нужно учиться дальше, Но очень интересно как такое реализовать куда смотреть в какую сторону копать? Как вообще в Django через админку манипулировать какими-либо элементами на Фронте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делаешь несколько моделей.

1. Непосредственно страница

```
class LandingPage(models.Model):
    page_title = models.Charfield(verbose_name="Заголовок", max_length=100)
    # ... остальные поля

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Страница"
        verbose_name_plural = "Страницы"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_title
```

2. блоки

```
class LandingBlock(models.Model):
    BLOCK_TYPE_SIMPLE_TEXT = 'text'
    BLOCK_TYPE_NEWS = 'news'
    BLOCK_TYPE_COMMENT = 'comment'
    BLOCK_TYPE_GALLERY = 'gallery'
    BLOCK_TYPE_FEED_BACK = 'feedback'
    BLOCK_TYPES = (
        (BLOCK_TYPE_SIMPLE_TEXT, "Текстовый блок"),
        (BLOCK_TYPE_NEWS, "Новостной блок"),
        (BLOCK_TYPE_COMMENT, "Комментарий"),
        (BLOCK_TYPE_GALLERY, "Фото галерея"),
        (BLOCK_TYPE_FEED_BACK, "Отзывы"),
    )

    page = models.ForeignKey(LandingPage, verbose_name="Страница", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    block_type = models.Charfield(verbose_name="Тип блока", choices=BLOCK_TYPES, default=BLOCK_TYPE_TEXT, max_length=100)
    npp = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name = "№", default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Страница"
        verbose_name_plural = "Страницы"
        ordering = ('npp',)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}. {} {}".format(self.page, self.npp, self.block_type)
```

Если захочешь можно тип блока вместо массива вынести в отдельную модель

затем в файле admin.py регистрируешь модели, добавив inline для блоков.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import LandingBlock, LandingPage

class BlockInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LandingBlock
    
    
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BlockInlineAdmin]

    
admin.site.register(LandingPage, PageAdmin)
```

Так же для того, что бы можно было легко перетаскивать блоки внутри страницы для сортировки, я бы поставил django-admin-sortable2
тогда admin.py будет выглядеть так(не забудь только добавить в settings.py это приложение, подробней об установке - https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableInlineAdminMixin
from .models import LandingBlock, LandingPage

class BlockInlineAdmin(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    model = LandingBlock
    
    
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BlockInlineAdmin]

    
admin.site.register(LandingPage, PageAdmin)
```

Ну и затем уже во view когда будешь готовить html для каждой страницы тебе нужно будет последовательный вывод блоков, которые привязаны к этой странице